# python regex: expression to match number and letters

Tags: python, regex, string

The aim is to print everything which does not end with `"_C[any number+letter]"`.

```
def regexer():

import re
name_list = ['chrome_PM', 'chrome_P', 'chromerocker_C', 'chromebike_P1', 
                 'chromecar_CMale', 'chromeone_C1254']

for name in name_list:
    counts_tail = re.compile('_C\d*$')
    if not counts_tail.search(name):
        print name
```

Output:

```
chrome_PM
chrome_P
chromebike_P1
chromecar_CMale
```

How can I edit my code to avoid printing "chromecar_CMale"?

Comment: do you want `'chromeone_C1254'` ?

Comment: It's kind of confusing what you're doing. You're currently printing what you are *not* catching?

Comment: It is unclear if you want to catch: `_[anyletter][number sequence]` or `_C[number+letter sequence]`.

Comment: Do not compile the pattern everytime inside the loop.

Comment: I'm printing anything which does not end with "_C[anynumber+letter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_C[\da-zA-Z]*$
```

This should do it.

Comment: this is not what OP want !

Comment: This is exactly what I want. it catches any element which ends with "_C[any number/letter]"

Comment: @Boosted_d16 i don't got down vote but , this regex mach any combinations between digits and letters contain just letters !!!

Comment: @Boosted_d16 it catches any element which ends with "_C[any number/letter]", then why you don't want `chromeone_C1254` ?

Comment: @Kasra - I'm catching given elements to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex like below,

```
>>> import re
>>> name_list = ['chrome_PM', 'chrome_P', 'chromerocker_C', 'chromebike_P1', 
                 'chromecar_CMale', 'chromeone_C1254']
>>> for name in name_list:
    if re.search(r'^(?!.*(?:_C\d+|_C)$)(?=.*_C)', name):
        print(name)


chromecar_CMale
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `(?!.*(?:_C\d+|_C)$)` This negative lookahead asserts that there wouldn't be anything like `_C` one or more digits or `_C` immediately followed by an end of the line anchor.
- `(?=.*_C)` Asserts that there must be a substring like `_C` would present.
- Match the string starts `^` only if the above conditions are satisfied.
- The above regex would be written as `^(?!.*_C(\d+)?$)(?=.*_C)`

Comment: You should consider providing an explanation of what your code does. ;)

Comment: Good stuff! I like the negative thinking you put into this.

Answer (score 0):

I would extend the regexp to accept words ([0-9a-zA-Z_]):

```
re.compile('_C\w+$')
```

Of course, that will accept any combination of letters or numbers. If you want to restrict it to letters or numbers only, you can do the following:

```
re.compile('_C(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)$')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's invert the logic here. You are searching for things you don't want, and filtering them out. Instead why not search for the things you want?

Your regexp could look like this: `_C[A-Za-z]+[\D]`, where:

- `_C` is the starting C you need
- `[A-Za-z]+` matches any lower/upper case letter more than once
- `[\D]` excludes there being digits after the letters, thus avoiding matching stuff like `chromecar_CM123`. Note: capital `\D` is the negation of the shorthand `\d`

So the Python code would become something like:

```python
import re

def regexer():
    name_list = ['chrome_PM', 'chrome_P', 'chromerocker_C', 'chromebike_P1', 
             'chromecar_CMale', 'chromeone_C1254']

    counts_tail = re.compile('_C[A-Za-z]+[\D]') # Build regexp here - no need to do it in the loop
    for name in name_list:
        if counts_tail.search(name):
            print name
```

Here is the regexp in action:

[image]